# How to add QLPreviewController as Subview in objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, qlpreviewcontroller

Is it possible to add QLPreviewController to UIView as sub view.

I tried like this

```
[self.view addSubview:previewViewController.view]
```

I also called `reloadData`

```
[previewViewController reloadData];
```

I check with this URL [Adding QLPreviewController as subview doesn't load PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043305/adding-qlpreviewcontroller-as-subview-doesnt-load-pdf) . But I did not understand what is `self.pdfPreviewView`

Please guide me how I can add QLPreviewController as sub view..

Comment: as of ios6 this is obsolete: 
see http://oleb.net/blog/2012/10/remote-view-controllers-in-ios-6/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes its possible, see the code below:

```
QLPreviewController* preview = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
preview.dataSource = self;
preview.delegate = self;
[self addChildViewController:preview];//*view controller containment
//set the frame from the parent view
CGFloat w= self.quickLookView.frame.size.width; 
CGFloat h= self.quickLookView.frame.size.height;
preview.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,w, h);
[self.quickLookView addSubview:preview.view];    
[preview didMoveToParentViewController:self];
//save a reference to the preview controller in an ivar
self.previewController = preview;
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I am having few queries here.. Because I am iOS beginner. Your saying to create ival for previewController. What about datatype is it UIViewController/QLPreviewController? quickLookView means, give me more details pls? +1

Comment: @NagaHarishMovva: Just create a UIViewController property named previewController in your Object - this should do the thing ;)

Comment: @railwayparade : It works very fine but i am facing an issue in iOS 5.0, when i rotate the view, the app crashes and it throws an execption: [QLPreviewController numberOfPreviewItems]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x9153600], please help me with this.

Comment: This will only work correctly if the view of the parent controller is already visible on the screen. If you try to add QLPreviewController as a child controller from the parent controller's loadView method, this won't work. You'll have to call if from viewDidAppear

Comment: Ug, there's hardly a time when you should do anything in loadView. viewDidLoad is a good place for the majority of this work. Also, instead of hard coding frames, use self.previewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; or the auto layout constraint way.

Comment: In my case on iOS 10 toolbar and navigation bar is shown inside preview (UIView). How I can remove bars from the preview (UIView)?

Comment: @Ramis : Did you find any solution to removing the bars in iOS 10?

Comment: @Jacob I did post Swift version.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3.x**

```
private var pVC: QLPreviewController?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // I do not not why, but it needs to be setup after delay.
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: setupPreview)
}

private func setupPreview() {
    if (pVC != nil) { return }

    let preview = QLPreviewController()
    preview.dataSource = self
    preview.delegate = self

    preview.view.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: previewView.frame.size)
    previewView.addSubview(preview.view)

    preview.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    pVC = preview
}
```