# Load word document into uiscrollview ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview, uiscrollview

As i am done with loading of pdf document into uiscrollview on the basis of number of pages.

How can we load word document into uiscrollview and also word document should be loaded into uiscrollview with the number of pages.

How can we load html file into uiscrollview.

Please i am looking for alternative of uiwebview, uidocumentinteractioncontroller and qlpreviewcontroller.

Any help and suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: WHere do you have the html file that you want to render in web view, on some server or in your local bundle?

Comment: Loading html file not a problem , loading a doc file can be tough.

Comment: i am loading html file from local bundle

Answer (score 0):

> i am done with uidocumentinteractioncontroller and qlpreviewcontroller

Those are the correct classes to use. Where are you getting stuck? Please edit your question with more detail, and I'll update this answer.

You could also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493419/how-to-add-qlpreviewcontroller-as-subview-in-objective-c).

Comment: i have used uidocumentinteractioncontroller and qlpreviewcontroller but i want to implement something like loading of word document and html file into uiscrollview