# addSubview not calling QLPreviewControllerDataSource instances when offline

Tags: ios, addsubview, qlpreviewcontroller

I have the following piece of code to add a `QLPreviewController` subview

```
{
    QLPreviewController *preview = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
    preview.delegate = self;
    preview.dataSource = self;
    [self addChildViewController:preview];
    [self.view addSubview:preview.view];
    [preview didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    self.previewController = preview;
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller
{
    return 1;
}

-(id) previewController:(QLPreviewController *)previewController previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return self.url;
}
```

`self.url` is an `NSURL that` is located in NSTemporaryDirectory - file://localhost//.../blah.pdf

My issue is that when my laptop is connected to the internet, the document shows up as a subview, but when my laptop is not connected, `numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController` & `previewItemAtIndex` do not get called.

- I've tried a vanilla program with a simple view controller, and it seemed to work fine. (My app is more complex than that).
- When I try presenting the document as a modal view, it seems to work irrespective of whether or not the simulator is connected to the internet.
  `[self presentViewController:preview animated:NO completion:nil];` --> works consistently.

I need to get the subview working for online & offline modes, it would be great if someone could help!

Comment: Try using this link worked for me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493419/how-to-add-qlpreviewcontroller-as-subview-in-objective-c

Answer (score 2):

You might be encountering strange behaviour because the QLPreviewController's view is not designed to be embedded in another view. From the [QLPreviewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) overview:

> To display a Quick Look preview controller you have two options: You can push it into view using a UINavigationController object, or can present it modally, full screen, using the presentModalViewController:animated: method of its parent class, UIViewController.

Having said that, you could try:

1. Forcing the QLPreviewController to (re)display its contents. Try adding `[self.previewController reloadData];` to the end of your first method. This should force the data source method(s) to fire.
2. Forcing the view to "refresh" it's subviews: `[self.view setNeedsLayout]` (which may in fact force a reloadData like the first option).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I had to force viewDidAppear to make it work, and that seemed to work fine for me.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Was stuck in this problem for long, [self.previewController reloadData] worked for me perfectly.